# How to access getServerSideProps on context?

Tags: next.js

I'm facing a structure issue on my project. A brief of what I'm doing:

On every page of my project, I do have a getServerSideProps function running that fetches the user and send it as a prop.

I do also have a UserContext file that fetches the user as well, to be accessed on my components.

The problem is that the user is being fetched twice, the UserContext is only there for me to access the user data on components.

What I was trying to achieve was getting the user data from the getServerSideProps directly into the context. But, I can not use getServerSideProps in non-page component and I can not use it on the _app.tsx as well.

What would be the best way to get the user data from the getServerSideProps on my components without sending it through props? (Basically the same functionality of UserContext but without fetching the user twice).

My getServerSideProps function:

```
import { destroyCookie, parseCookies, setCookie } from "nookies"
import { ICustomer } from "../types/customer.type"
import { ITemplate } from "../types/template.type"
import { getAPI } from "./api"

export function isAuthStore() {

    return async (ctx: any) => {

        const { 'nextauth.token': token, 'nextauth.refreshtoken': refreshtoken } = parseCookies(ctx)

        const path = String(ctx.req.url)

        let hasToken = false
        if (token || refreshtoken) {
            hasToken = true
        }

        let user: ICustomer | null = null
        let template: ITemplate | null = null

        const api = getAPI(ctx)

        if (!hasToken) {

            if (path.startsWith('/app')) {
                return {
                    redirect: {
                        destination: '/',
                        permanent: false
                    }
                }
            }

            await api.get('/v1/website/template', {
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'
                },
                params: {
                    trophies: true
                }
            })
                .then((res) => {
                    template = res.data.template
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    return {
                        redirect: {
                            destination: '/not-found',
                            permanent: false
                        }
                    }
                })

        } else {


            let requests = []

            requests.push(
                await api.get('/v1/auth/me', {
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'
                    },
                    params: {
                        trophies: true
                    }
                })
                    .then((res) => {
                        return {
                            success: true,
                            ref: 'user',
                            doc: res.data.user
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        return {
                            success: false,
                            ref: 'user'
                        }
                    })
            )

            requests.push(
                await api.get('/v1/website/template', {
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'
                    },
                    params: {
                        trophies: true
                    }
                })
                    .then((res) => {
                        return {
                            success: true,
                            ref: 'template',
                            doc: res.data.template
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        return {
                            success: false,
                            ref: 'template'
                        }
                    })
            )

            const results: { ref: string, success: boolean, doc?: {} }[] = await Promise.all(requests)

            for (const r of results) {
                if (r.success === false) {
                    if (r.ref === 'user') {
                        destroyCookie(ctx, 'nextauth.token')
                        destroyCookie(ctx, 'nextauth.refreshtoken')
                        return {
                            redirect: {
                                destination: '/',
                                permanent: false
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        return {
                            redirect: {
                                destination: '/not-found',
                                permanent: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (r.ref === 'user') {
                        user = r.doc! as ICustomer
                    } else {
                        template = r.doc! as ITemplate
                    }
                }
            }


            if (path.startsWith('/login') || path.startsWith('/register') || path.startsWith('/recover')) {
                return {
                    redirect: {
                        destination: '/app',
                        permanent: false
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return {
            props: {
                user,
                template
            }
        }

    }


}
```

My Context:

```
import { parseCookies } from "nookies";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loader from "../components/loader";
import { ContextData } from "../types/customer.type";
import { getAPI } from "../utils/api";

export const UserContext = React.createContext<ContextData>({} as ContextData)

export const UserProvider = (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

    const { 'nextauth.token': token, 'nextauth.refreshtoken': refreshtoken } = parseCookies()

    const loadUser = async () => {
        if (token || refreshtoken) {
            const api = getAPI()
            await api.get('/v1/auth/me')
                .then((res) => {
                    setUser(res.data.user)
                    setLoading(false)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setUser(null)
                    setLoading(false)
                })
        } else {
            setUser(null)
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadUser()
    }, [])

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, loadUser }}>
            {
                loading ?
                    <Loader />
                    :
                    props.children
            }
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )

}
```